# Key error in Python and Gurobi when doing iteration for a 3D matrix

Tags: python, gurobi

I am doing a linear integer programming for a planning optimization. We are looking at planning the production of multi-product with multi-stage operations in a 12 weeks' period:

```
6 products
4 stages 
12 weeks
```

This is one of our constraints.

```
#model.addConstrs((((P[i, s, t] * L.iloc[i, s] for i in range(products)) <= (H * W[s, t] + O[s, t])) for s in range(stages) for t in range(time_periods)), "capacity")
```

We got an error message "Key error (5,0,0)", which means that our model could not iterate in the s and t s.

How can I proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

A KeyError indicates that there is no tuple `(i,s,t)` within `P`. You could create a full set of variables for all combinations using

```
model.addVars(products, stages, time_periods, ...)
```

Reference: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addvars.html